# Vector Calculus Basics

Tags: vectors

Q. If the linear velocity is given by 
$$
V=(x^2y) \hat{i}+ {xyz} \hat{j}+ (-yz^2) \hat{k} 
$$
then the angular velocity at the point $(1,1,-1)$ is

I tried using the vector product on $V = w \times r$ to get $r \times V = w(r\cdot r) - r(r \cdot w)$.
On equating both sides, I got 3 linear equations in 3 variables. But it has no solution. 
Is there any mistake in this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about angular velocity about the origin. Note that $$\bar{\omega}=\frac{\hat{r}}{r} \times \bar{V}$$

Since $$\frac{\hat{r}}{r} =  \frac{x\hat{i} +y \hat{j}+  z  \hat{k} }{r^2}$$ we are left with a simple cross product to carry out.

Comment: If my algebra was correct, the angular velocity is $$\frac{-2}{3}(\hat{i}+\hat{k})$$

Comment: For that (w.r) must be 0 which should come eventually. Can you point out what's wrong with my approach?

Comment: The cross product formula you have used is true for any 3 vectors. You are therefore ignoring the extra info you have, namely that omega, r and V all three are mutually perpendicular to each other.  In particular $\omega \cdot r = 0$. Not using that info is why you find your system indeterminate.

Comment: I got it !! Thanks alot Mathemagical.